# How to convert this Python script to a shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, terminal, executable

This is a python script.

```
with open('a') as f:
    a, b = f
    a, b = a.strip(), b.strip()
```

it simply opens the file "a" and then first line becomes a, second line becomes b

now i can use a and b anywhere in the python script.

example:

```
print a
print b
```

I need code that is exactly like this but for Bash.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=linux+shell+scripting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr

http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/

Comment: How is python code not a Linux executable script? It runs on Linux and if you set execute permissions, it's executable.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, i need it for bash, i will not be executing it via `python script` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set permision as execution and add this at first line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: modern distros need `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, because `#!/usr/bin/env python` points to python3

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to add a shebang line
to the top of your script like so:

`#!/bin/python`

Where the portion after the shebang "#!" Is the path to your python environment which is often /bin/python on Linux platforms.

After that you will need to use the chmod command to make the file executable.

`chmod u+x /path/to/file`

This command will make the file executable for the user. You will then be able to run the script by just typing the path to the file into the command line.

Comment: The path to the python environment will depend on the operating system and/or whether the OP built python from source. So /usr/bin/python2 may or not be correct for the OP.